# No visualiza video

Tags: html5

Estoy haciendo un sitio web en donde tengo que reproducir videos.

Tengo el video fp-s1c1-pres.mp4 y si lo reproduce

```
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay>
 <source src="videos/fp-s1c1-pres.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
```

Pero cuando pongo el video Secuencia01.mp4 no lo visualiza nada mas reproduce el sonido

```
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay>
 <source src="videos/Secuencia01.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
```

Por que esta haciendo eso??

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esas son las propiedades del video

Propiedades que tiene de diferente el primer video

```
ancho fotograma 1280 
alto fotograma 818 
velocidad de datos 2935 kbps 
velocidad de bits total 3045 kbps 
tamaño 69.5 MB
```

Comment: Asegúrate en primer lugar que la integridad del segundo vídeo sea  buena.

Comment: A que te refieres con eso,no te entiendo??

Comment: me refiero a que el vídeo se reproduzca bien en la carpeta en la cual la tienes.

Comment: Esto puede deberse a los codecs, el archivo sin duda existe ya que puedes escuchar el sonido, puedes agregar las propiedades de el archivo /Secuencia01.mp4, puedes compartir el archivo?

Comment: @Jorgesys aqui muestro las propiedades del video con el que estoy teniendo problemas

Comment: @JorgeAlejandroAlonsoGutierr recuerda agregar actualizaciones a tu pregunta con la opción [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/144537/edit) Que propiedades ves diferente  a  el archivo fp-s1c1-pres.mp4

Comment: @Jorgesys ya actualize la publicacion con las propiedades que tiene diferentes el primer video

Comment: Encontre la solucion, resulta que el segundo video estaba mal codificado y ahi es donde estaba el problema

Answer (score 1):

Deber usar controls="" porque si no usas controls no se mostrará el reproductor.

```html
<video width="320" height="240" controls="" autoplay>
 <source src="videos/Secuencia01.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
```